# Karma and Firefox with WSL

Tags: karma-runner, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I would like to run karma tests using Firefox under WSL. I have firefox installed via apt and it is working using VcXsrv in Windows. When I use karma-firefox-launcher, however, I get a "Cannot start Firefox" error. Has anybody successfully gotten this to work? If so, how?

Comment: You are likely to have better luck running the Windows version of FF, which can launch from WSL.

Answer (score 21):

Hello I've faced with this problem, but instead of FF it was the Google chrome, and it took awhile to figure it out. So I'll publish my solution here, maybe it can help someone.

If you are windows user on WSL and you are trying to run `ng test` you will get an error which says

> No binary for Chrome browser on your platform. Please, set
> "CHROME_BIN" env variable.

Reason is that actually you don't have chrome on you linux machine and you are trying to run your tests in it.

My solution is to create an alias from linux to windws's chrome

```
alias launchchrome="\"/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe\""
```

and after that export it as a linux env variable

```
export CHROME_BIN=launchchrome
```

That's it, now if you run `ng test` your standard chrome will be used!

Comment: An obvious side note but relavant for any fool like me thatt didn't check but if you've installed the 64but version of Chrome you want to tweak it to go to 'Program Files' and not 'Program Files (x86)'.

Comment: This is a good idea but unfortunately it's not working for me

Comment: If anybody still having this issue try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65107381