# Selenium Drivers unable to build in GitHub Actions

Tags: selenium-webdriver, gradle, github-actions, cicd, webdrivermanager-java

I am currently trying to get Selenium tests to be able to run using Gradle with GitHub actions. I am trying to run the job on a local server to get past two-factor auth. The tests are able to run locally and when running the tests not on our local servers, the Selenium drivers are able to build.

Here are the errors I receive:

```
  
    Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Driver server process died prematurely.
```

[image]

Here is my gradle.yml file:

```
name: Java CI with Gradle

on:
  push:
    branches: ["dev"]
  pull_request:
    branches: ["dev"]

permissions:
  contents: read

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: [some place where I work]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Set up JDK 19
        uses: actions/setup-java@v2
        with:
          java-version: "19"
      - name: Grant execute permission for gradlew
        run: chmod +x gradlew
      - name: Build with Gradle
        run: ./gradlew test --info
```

build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    implementation 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:4.8.0'
    testImplementation("io.github.bonigarcia:webdrivermanager:5.3.2")
}
```

JDK version: 19

Selenium: 4.8.0

WebDriverManager: 5.3.2

I have tried updated my versions of JDK, Selenium, and WebDriverManager but have had no success.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Error while loading shared libraries: libnss3.so" while running Gtlab CI job to perform automated testing using webdriverio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58134793/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libnss3-so-while-running-gtlab-ci-job-to)

Comment: I does not. I am not using Gitlab or having the same error they were.

Comment: The red error in your screenshot says otherwise. It's not a Gitlab or Github issue. It's that the runner doesn't have to required dependencies installed.

Comment: Last line in your screenshot: `/home/docker/cache/selenium/chromedriver/linux64/110-0-5481.77/chromedriver: error while loading shared libraries: libnss3.so: cannot open shared object file: NO Such file or directory`

Comment: This is why we recommend to put the whole log messages as plaintext in the StackOverflow Q&A.